# Como usar o SimpleDateFormat em ambientes concorrentes?

Tags: java, datetime, thread-safety

A classe [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) não é *thread safe*. Recentemente tive problemas com instâncias da classe `SimpleDateFormat` em contexto estático sendo usadas por múltiplas threads concorrentemente em uma aplicação Web.

```java
private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Como devo proceder para garantir a sincronização / concorrência com o mínimo de *overhead*? Por exemplo, devo usar `syncronized`, criar uma instância [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) ou quem sabe criar uma nova instância do objeto `SimpleDateFormat` a cada chamada para o método de formatação de datas (pagando o preço da construção do objeto)?

Comment: Larga esse SDT e usa JODA!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O preço da construção do objeto normalmente é baixíssimo. A menos que você esteja criando vários `DateFormats` em um laço (possivelmente debaixo de muitas camadas de abstração), e o tempo de criação do `DateFormat` esteja dominando o tempo de execução, então o melhor a fazer é usar o construtor.

Mesmo se o caso for este, normalmente será possível refatorar o código de forma a colocar o `DateFormat` em uma variável local ou em um parâmetro (ainda mais que no código original ele estava em uma variável estática). O funcionamento é semelhante ao de encapsular o uso de um campo e ao invés disso colocar em getter. Por exemplo:

```java
// Antes:
private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

private void metodoPrincipal() {
   ... blablabla ...
   metodoQualquer();
   ... blablabla ...
}

private void metodoQualquer() {
   ... blablabla ...
   x = df.metodoQualquer(parametros);
   ... blablabla ...
}

// Depois
private static final DateFormat createFormat() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
}

private void metodoPrincipal() {
   ... blablabla ...
   metodoQualquer(createFormat());
   ... blablabla ...
}

private void metodoQualquer(DateFormat df) {
   ... blablabla ...
   x = df.metodoQualquer(parametros);
   ... blablabla ...
}
```

Se isso implicar em você ter que colocar parâmetros em dezenas de lugares e com isso quebrar a assinatura de muitos métodos, talvez o `ThreadLocal` seja uma alternativa melhor.

Se você pretende usar o Java 8 ou superior, você definitivamente poderá usar a classe [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Como citado na documentação (em inglês) ela é imutável e *thread-safe*. Utilizando esta nova classe, o seu problema desaparece.

Answer (score 8):

Eu pessoalmente acho melhor deixar de lado todas as classes de data e hora pré-Java 8 e usar o [JODA Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). O JODA Time de forma geral é imutável e thread-safe. Com ele, ficaria assim:

```java
// A diferença DateTimeFormatter/DateTimeFormat não é erro
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTime date = formatter.parseDateTime("11/12/2013")
String text = formatter.print(date);
```

No Java 8 existe uma nova API, resultado da [JSR-310](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/threeten/) (ver também o [github](http://threeten.github.io/) do projeto), que teve por inspiração o JODA Time. Apesar disso, essa [API](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/package-summary.html) é ligeiramente diferente, e ficaria assim:

```java
// qualquer das classes de data pode ser usada no lugar de LocalDate abaixo
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("11/12/2013", formatter);
String text = date.toString(formatter);
```

Se você estiver usando Java 7, tem também a opção de um [backport do JSR-310](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp). A base do import é diferente (`org.threeten.bp` ao invés de `java.time`), mas o resto do código é essencialmente igual.

Assim como o parser/formatter, as classes de data e hora, duração, interval e instante, tanto do Java 8 quanto do JODA Time, são imutáveis e thread safe.

Comment: Enquanto a resposta do Victor é a mais precisa para a pergunta que eu fiz, acredito que o JODA Time seja a melhor opção em geral. Tenho certeza que dessa vez a [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) co-liderada pelo nosso querido Michael Nascimento Santos será incluída no Java 8, mas até lá, nada como o [JODA Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/java-best-practices-dateformat-in.html, usar `ThreadLocal` é o que dá maior performance. Analise o contexto e veja se instanciar os objetos não tem um custo muito alto.

Comment: É o que eu faço quando é necessário suportar múltiplas threads neste component.

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa tão simples e <del>quase insignificantemente</del> mais "performática" à criação sob demanda de instâncias do `SimpleDateFormat`, conforme apresentado pelo Victor, é a clonagem.

Um teste de desempenho é apresentado [nesta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5038489/1683070), onde a clonagem chega a ser quase 3 vezes mais eficiente.

Vejamos um exemplo de implementação:

```java
static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
static DateFormat createFormat() {
    return (DateFormat) df.clone();
}
```

Por outro lado, na mesma página citada acima, o método que apresentou melhor desempenho foi a criação de um *pool* de instâncias. Neste conceito, um número `n` de instâncias da classe `SimpleDateFormat` onde `n >= nº de threads`, é a forma mais eficiente.

Entretanto, minha resposta visa apenas contribuir com algumas particularidades sobre o tema. Eu concordo que a quase totalidade dos aplicativos desenvolvidos não necessita de tal "otimização", pois existem inúmeros outros gargalos que impactam mais no desempenho geral da aplicação.